# value assigned to all hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

My script is assigning an element (tickets[4])to a hash.

array of hash looks like this

```
all = [{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}, {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}]
```

Array tickets looks like this

```
tickets = [["hello","2014-01-02","1","Clôturé","2"], ["hello","2014-01-03","1","Clôturé","1"]]
```

After the script runs it should result with

```
all = [{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}}, {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}]
```

Instead I have

```
all = [{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}}, {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}}]
```

It is assigning the value 2 for all the key. I want my script to assign only to a specific key "hello" in this case and not "hello" and "bye"

```
 tickets.each do |t|
    d_d = Date.strptime(t[1],"%d-%m-%Y")
    n_c = t[0].to_s
    all.each do |e|
        e.each do |nom,pair|
            pair.each do |d,tick|
                 d1 = Date.strptime(d,"%d-%m-%Y")
                 if n_c == nom.to_s && d1 == d_d
                 p pair[d] = t[4]
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If, in your first array of hashes, you had `{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>3, "2014-01-03"=>0}}`, would the desired result contain `"2014-01-02"=>2` or `"2014-01-02"=>5`? Are the values in the first array of hashes always all zero? You may wish to clarify that with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it:

```
all = [{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}, {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}]
tickets = [["hello","2014-01-02","1","Clôturé","2"], ["hello","2014-01-03","1","Clôturé","1"]]

tickets.each do |ticket|
  # This is the same as:
  #  name = ticket[0]
  #  date = ticket[1]
  name, date = ticket[0..1]

  # Here we're finding the correct ticket in "all" array.
  # The "correct ticket" is the hash whose key is equal the "name"
  all_ticket = all.select { |h| h.keys.first == name }.first

  # If the "correct ticket" still doesn't have a count, we attribute 0 to it
  all_ticket[name][date] ||= 0

  # And here we're incrementing its count
  all_ticket[name][date] += ticket.last.to_i
end

# Prints the result
p all
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def aggregate(all, tickets)
  tickets_tot = tickets.each_with_object({}) { |(word, date, *_, nbr),h|
    h[[word, date]] = nbr.to_i }     
  all.map do |h|
    word, g = h.to_a.first
    f = g.each_with_object({}) { |(date,nbr),f| f[date] = nbr.to_i +
      tickets_tot.fetch([word, date], 0) }
    { word=>f }
  end
end
```

**Example**

For `all` and `tickets` given in the question,

```
aggregate(all, tickets)
  #=> [{"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}},
  #    {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}]
```

Here

```
tickets_tot
  #=> {["hello", "2014-01-02"]=>2, ["hello", "2014-01-03"]=>1}
```

**Explanation**

Let's step through the calculations.

*> Calculate `tickets_tot`*

For efficiency reasons, we first compute `tickets_tot`, as that requires only a single pass through `tickets`. The alternative is to enumerate `tickets` for each value of `all`.

First define the enumerator

```
enum = tickets.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["hello", "2014-01-02", "1", "Clôturé", "2"],
  #    ["hello", "2014-01-03", "1", "Clôturé", "1"]]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of `enum` is generated, passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values.

```
(word, date, *_, nbr),h = enum.next
  #=> [["hello", "2014-01-02", "1", "Clôturé", "2"], {}]
word
  #=> "hello"
date
  #=> "2014-01-02"
_ #=> ["1", "Clôturé"]
nbr
  #=> "2"
h #=> {}
```

`*_` assigns the variable `_` to an array of all values between `date` and `nbr`. (Note that IRB uses the variable `_` for its own purposes, so it does not report its value correctly.) The underscore was used to signify that this variable is not used in the block calculation.

The hash `h` is initially empty, but that will change as calculations are performed.

The block calculation is next performed.

```
h[[word, date]] = nbr.to_i
h[["hello", "2014-01-02"]] = 2
```

The next and last value generated by `enum` is now passed to the block.

```
(word, date, *_, nbr),h = enum.next
  #=> [["hello", "2014-01-03", "1", "Clôturé", "1"],
  #    {["hello", "2014-01-02"]=>2}]
word
  #=> "hello"
date
  #=> "2014-01-03"
_ #=> ["1", "Clôturé"]
nbr
  #=> "1"
h #=> {["hello", "2014-01-02"]=>2}
```

Notice that `h` has been updated. We then perform the block calculation.

```
h[[word, date]] = nbr.to_i
  #=> h[["hello", "2014-01-03"]] = 1
```

Lastly,

```
tickets_tot = h
  #=> {["hello", "2014-01-02"]=>2, ["hello", "2014-01-03"]=>1}
```

*> Map `all` to the desired array of hashes*

We now turn to the to the second part of the calculation. The first value of `all` is passed to `map`'s block, the block variable is assigned its value and block is executed.

```
h = all[0]
  #=> {"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}
a = h.to_a
  #=> [["hello", {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}]]
word, g = a.first
  #=> ["hello", {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}]
word
  #=> "hello"
g #=> {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}
f = g.each_with_object({}) { |(date,nbr),f| f[date] = nbr.to_i +
    tickets_tot.fetch([word, date], 0) }
  #=> {"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}
```

See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

```
{ word=>f }
  #=> {"hello"=>{"2014-01-02"=>2, "2014-01-03"=>1}}
```

This updated the values in the first hash. Lastly,

```
h = all[1]
  #=> {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}
a = h.to_a
  #=> [["bye", {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}]]
word, g = a.first
  #=> ["bye", {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}]
word
  #=> "bye"
g #=> {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}
f = g.each_with_object({}) { |(date,nbr),f| f[date] = nbr.to_i +
    tickets_tot.fetch([word, date], 0) }
  #=> {"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}
```

This time `fetch`'s default value of `0` is used.

```
{ word=>f }
  # => {"bye"=>{"2014-01-02"=>0, "2014-01-03"=>0}}
```

This mapping is unchanged from the initial hash. `map` therefore returns the given array of two hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! The script was working well, but ruby was considering the date as the same object. I had to add ".clone" when creating my hash with all the dates.

```
nom.each do |n|
    hash = {}
    hash = {n => dates.clone}
    all << hash
end
```